# Equation of silhouette from an arbitrary viewpoint

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

A two parameter $(u,v)$ surface in $\mathbb R^3$ when viewed from a point at infinite distance casts a shadow on any given plane.

What ODE/PDE describes its envelope of its silhouetted projection?

EDIT 1:

For a simple example circular helices on a cylinder project their cylinder generators as its envelope or shadow border.

EDIT2:

Sufficiently large 2D surfaces defined with two parameters in 3D using CASs.. entail visualizing these characteristic silhouette lines from any viewpoint.